# Pure TensorFlow vs Keras // Tensorflow solves the problem but Keras doesn't - When to use Keras and when TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I made exactly the same experience as this person [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869939/something-wrong-with-keras-code-q-learning-openai-gym-frozenlake). In a nutshell: Pure TensorFlow code solves this Open AI gym problem well (0.352% success) but Keras doesn't (0.052% success).

On the question I linked there's no solution posted and it got only few attention.

---

Therefore I would like to ask in a more general way:

1. Why can it happen that TensorFlow works fine but Keras doesn't?
2. How should you deal with that issue if you want to use Keras?

There are several questions about the advantages of pure TF compared to Keras, but the answers largely say that Keras is the same as TF (except some unimportant things, e.g. layernames), just shorter and you have slightly less control.

But given that situation you apparently can't rely on the fact that Keras works as fine as pure TF.
So:

3. When can you rely on Keras working as fine as pure TF?

Comment: If you're comparing to Juliani's code at the end of [this post](https://link.medium.com/S0T1oXVSs5) it seems quite different from the Keras model in the other question. In the post is not really even a neural net, it's a linear model. There are no hidden layers, and not even output activation. There is no bias. The weights are initialized at random with values in [0, 0.01). The learning rate is set to 0.1. The other question has a more complex network with different initialization, probably takes longer to train.

Comment: Read this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.06560 before making any claims on comparing RL algorithms between TF and Keras.